# id3lib: copying frames does not work

Tags: c++, id3lib

I'm trying to copy all ID3v2 tags from one file to another. But my code does not work (the tags remain unchanged) and I do not know why.

```
ID3_Tag sFile, tFile;

sFile.Link("source.mp3", ID3TT_ID3V2);
tFile.Link("target.mp3");

tFile.Strip();

ID3_Tag::Iterator* sFrItr = sFile.CreateIterator();
ID3_Frame* sFrame = NULL;
while (NULL != (sFrame = sFrItr->GetNext()))
{
    tFile.AddFrame(sFrame);
}
delete sFrItr;

tFile.Update();
```

This code is mostly based on [id3lib API example](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/index.html). I didn't have anything to do with id3 earlier, so I might just not be understanding how the frames and fields work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that when `Update()` is triggered, the `ID3_Frame`s added to `tFile` do not exist anymore. The correct way is to create pointers to copies of `ID3_Frame`s and attach them to the `ID3_Tag`:

```
while (NULL != (sFrame = sFrItr->GetNext()))
{
    tFile.AttachFrame(new ID3_Frame(*sFrame));
}
```

`AttachFrame()` takes care of the memory and deletes the data itself afterwards.